# How to Call function with default parameter?

Tags: c++

I have a function define in header file as this:

```
int myfunction(VpTR*& viewporttable,  wchar* vpname=L"*Active", OpenMode f=fR);
```

how i can call this function but ignore second argument?
I tried calling it with the following code but an error message appeared: **expected an expression**

```
myfunction(myviewporttable,, fR);
```

can i omit this argument but it still understands L "* Active" as the called value?

Comment: You can't. C++ doesn't have named parameters support some other languages have so you cannot omit any parameter

Comment: You can still call it with arguments: myfunction(myviewportable, L"*Active", fR)

Comment: Make a helper forwarding function `int myfunction(VpTR*& viewporttable, OpenMode f) { return myfunction(viewporttable, L"*Active", f); }`

Comment: Thanks everyone, my problem is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax doesn't allow to omit parameter values at arbitrary positions, only those at the very end of the list.

You have to overload 2 versions:

```
int myfunction(VpTR*& viewporttable,  OpenMode f=fR) {
    return myfunction(viewporttable,L"*Active",L"*Active",f);
}

int myfunction(VpTR*& viewporttable,  wchar* vpname=L"*Active", OpenMode f=fR);
```

Then you can call

```
myfunction(myviewporttable, fR);
```